# Greek words recognition while reading url with python

Tags: python, encoding, words

I'm new python programmer. I have written a simple script that is doing the following:

- asks url from the user
- reads the url (urlopen(url).read())
- tokenizes the result of the above command

I take the result of the tokenization in two files. The one has words in latin characters (english, spanish etc) and the other one the rest (greek words etc).

The problem is that, when I open a greek url, I take the greek from it, but I see it as a sequence of characters, not words (as it happens in the latin case).

I expect to take a list of the words (`μαρια`, `γιωργος`, `παιδι`) (number of items 3) but what i take is `('μ','α','ρ','ι', 'α'........)` number of items as many as the letters

What should I do? (the encoding is utf-8)

Follows the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Importing useful libraries 
#NOTE: Nltk should be installed first!!!
import nltk
import urllib #mporei na einai kai urllib
import re
import lxml.html.clean
import unicodedata
from urllib import urlopen

http = "http://"
www = "www."
#pattern = r'[^\a-z0-9]'

#Demand url from the user
url=str(raw_input("Please, give a url and then press ENTER: \n"))


#Construct a valid url syntax
if (url.startswith("http://"))==False:
    if(url.startswith("www"))==False:
        msg=str(raw_input("Does it need 'www'? Y/N \n"))
        if (msg=='Y') | (msg=='y'):
            url=http+www+url
        elif (msg=='N') | (msg=='n'):
            url=http+url
        else:
            print "You should type 'y' or 'n'"
    else:
        url=http+url

latin_file = open("Latin_words.txt", "w")
greek_file = open("Other_chars.txt", "w")
latin_file.write(url + '\n')
latin_file.write("The latin words of the above url are the following:" + '\n')
greek_file.write("Οι ελληνικές λέξεις καθώς και απροσδιόριστοι χαρακτήρες")

#Reading the given url

raw=urllib.urlopen(url).read()

#Retrieve the html body from the url. Clean it from html special characters
pure = nltk.clean_html(raw)
text = pure

#Retrieve the words (tokens) of the html body in a list
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

counter=0
greeks=0
for i in tokens:
    if re.search('[^a-zA-Z]', i):
        #greeks+=1
        greek_file.write(i)
    else:
        if len(i)>=4:
            print i
            counter+=1
            latin_file.write(i + '\n')
        else:
            del i


#Print the number of words that I shall take as a result
print "The number of latin tokens is: %d" %counter

latin_file.write("The number of latin tokens is: %d and the number of other characters is: %d" %(counter, greeks))
latin_file.close()
greek_file.close()
```

I checked it in many ways, and, as far as I can get it, the program just recognises greek characters but fails to recognise greek words, meaning, the space with witch we seperate words!

If i type greek sentences with space in my terminal, it appears correctly. The problem occurs when i read something (like body from html page)

In addition, in text_file.write(i), regarding the greek i's, if i write text_file.write(i+ '\n'), the result is unidentified characters, aka, i lose my encoding!

Any ideas concerning the above?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: What do you mean 'sequence of characters'? Like this: `['a','b','c']` and you were expecting `'abc'`? Post some code so we don't have this back and forth :)

Comment: Hint: `print tokens` should tell you what you are getting back; and then you can adjust your for loop appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

here I think you're looking for substrings not strings `if re.search('[^a-zA-Z]', i)`
you can get words from the list by looping the list `token`

Comment: i see what you mean, but how am i supposed to distinguish latin words from the rest? Don't need I some regex?

Comment: if `re.search('[^greek letters]', i) in i`

Comment: I mean here, try to check if word contain greek letter and if it does it must be greek word

Answer (score 0):

Python `re` module is notorious for its weak unicode support. For serious unicode work consider the alternative [regex module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/0.1.20120904), that fully supports unicode scripts and properties. Example:

```
text = u"""
Some latin words, for example: cat niño määh fuß
Οι ελληνικές λέξεις καθώς και απροσδιόριστοι χαρακτήρες
"""

import regex

latin_words = regex.findall(ur'\p{Latin}+', text)
greek_words = regex.findall(ur'\p{Greek}+', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your code, using the excellent [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) for fetching URLs, the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) to automatically close files and [`io`](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html) to help with utf8.

```
import io
import nltk
import requests
import string

url = raw_input("Please, give a url and then press ENTER: \n")
if not url.startswith('http://'):
   url = 'http://'+url
page_text = requests.get(url).text
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(page_text)

latin_words = [w for w in tokens if w.isalpha()]
greek_words = [w for w in tokens if w not in latin_words]

print 'The number of latin tokens is {0}'.format(len(latin_words))

with (io.open('latin_words.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as latin_file,
      io.open('greek_words.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as greek_file):

    greek_file.writelines(greek_words)
    latin_file.writelines(latin_words)

    latin_file.write('The number of latin words is {0} and the number of others {1}\n'.format(len(latin_words),len(greek_words))
```

I simplified the part that checks for the URL; this way invalid URLs will not be read.